# Getting Cell Value from a range based on Column Name

Tags: excel, vba, range, cell

I have a requirement to change the following code to this:

Now:

```
'in a loop with a being rownumber     
CurrInvoiceNum = ws2.Range("B" & a).Value
```

Required:

```
' Transaction ID is the column name of B and the reason for the change is that it need not always be in B.
CurrInvoiceNum = ws2.Range("Transaction ID" & a).Value
```

I tried getting cells like this:

```
Cells.Find(What:="Transaction ID", LookAt:=xlWhole).Column )
```

but could not make it use of the rownumber..

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First approach** - using `Application.Match` (faster one):

```
Dim colNum

With ws2
    colNum = Application.Match("Transaction ID", .Range("1:1"), 0)
    If IsError(colNum) Then
        MsgBox "Column with header 'Transaction ID' not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    CurrInvoiceNum = .Cells(a, colNum).Value
End With
```

**Second approach** - using `.Find`:

```
Dim rng As Range

With ws2
    Set rng = .Range("1:1").Find(What:="Transaction ID", LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Column with header 'Transaction ID' not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    CurrInvoiceNum = .Cells(a, rng.Column).Value
End With
```

both apporaches assumes that your headers are in first row: `.Range("1:1")`

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the column name is in the first row:

```
Sub dural()
    Set r = Rows(1).Find(What:="Transaction Id")
    a = 7
    CurrInvoiceNum = r.Offset(a - 1, 0).Value
End Sub
```